# pdsh works well standalone, but doesn't work in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to install hadoop via script on my small cluster [introduced in the book: Apache Hadoop Yarn]. I have set up ssh connect without password, and pdsh&pdcp are all fine if I use it alone. The problem is when I put the command in script, pdsh and pdcp fail. I really don't understand where goes wrong.

works when use it standalone:

`pdcp -R ssh -w ^all_hosts hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz /opt`

here is part of the script that doesn't work:  Whole script click [here](https://gist.github.com/legatoo/5d1283a62574dbc60bd4)

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> HADOOP_VERSION=2.5.1
> install()
> {
>     echo "Copying Hadoop $HADOOP_VERSION to all hosts..."
>     pdcp -R ssh -w ^all_hosts hadoop-"$HADOOP_VERSION".tar.gz /opt
> ....
> ```

all_hosts file is like this (hostname):

> ```
> dave
>
> micheal
>
> jose
> ```

the error is:

> ```
> micheal: Host key verification failed.
> pdcp@dave: micheal: ssh exited with exit code 255
> jose: Host key verification failed.
> pdcp@dave: jose: ssh exited with exit code 255
> dave: Host key verification failed.
> pdcp@dave: dave: ssh exited with exit code 255
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The "Host key verification failed" is from the underlying SSH process. See [pdcp(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/pdcp.1.html#contenttoc10):

> When using ssh for remote execution, stderr of ssh to be folded in
>   with that  of  the remote command.  When invoked by pdcp, it is not
>   possible for ssh to prompt for confirmation if a host key  changes, 
>   prompt  for passwords  if RSA keys are not configured properly, etc..

A solution would be to connect to all hosts in `all_hosts` *once* before and to accept their host keys or to *disable* (!) [StrictHostKeyChecking](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for said hosts:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host dave micheal jose
        StrictHostKeyChecking   no

$ pdcp -R ssh -w ^all_hosts mate-terminal /opt
sid0: Warning: Permanently added 'micheal,192.168.0.130' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
[...]
```

Comment: You can also use `Host *` to set it for all hosts

Answer (score 1):

Since this error comes from the underlying SSH process, we can actually pass an option to it to either automatically add the host to the known hosts or ignore the host key checking this one time. You can use the `PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND` environment variable to pass these options to the underlying process.

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" pdcp -R ssh -w ^all_hosts hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz /opt
```

This environment variable works for straight pdsh as well.